# How to activate sortable using mousedown event instead of drag event using Jquery UI Sortable?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Jquery UI Sortable for re-ordering a table rows. The drag-drop is working as expected, but I need to activate sortable using moousedown event instead of drag event. Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/O6xkgVrXUAgXwcBon5ph?p=preview) for the same.

```
angular.element(el).sortable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    helper: fixWidthHelper
}).disableSelection();

function fixWidthHelper(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        angular.element(this).width(angular.element(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
}
```

Comment: `jQuery UI sortable` doesn't have drag event. It has just start and stop event. Please see https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: @AliSoltani, We will be able to sort items only if we will start dragging. But I want sorting should happen using mousedown event too.

Comment: Another things is as far as I know there is no way to override events in jQuery sortable.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera how do you or the user know which item to move when pressing down arrow key? This is not something sortable can do, but would have to be done to adjust the items position and then update sortable after.

Comment: @Twisty What I want here is, when user mousedown on any item, the selected item should be dragged and on mouseup the item should be dropped somewhere. Basically, the user shouldn't drag some item to drop somewhere.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera which item is the selected item?

Comment: @Twisty User can select any row from the table randomly. So, every row's are selectable.

Comment: @UmakantaBehera What triggers the selection, how do you know what has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, `.sortable()`, must use mouse interaction, `click` + `drag` + `drop`, to be able to move items. It cannot move items via keyboard interaction.

You can write a function to simulate this activity. But you still need some way to gain "focus" on one of your items to then move it to a different position. You will never get away from `click` event. Maybe that is enough.

Here is the default Sortable example with some extra functions:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7r55c9wb/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function clickFocus(e) {
    $(".ui-state-focus").removeClass("ui-state-focus");
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-focus");
    $(e.target).blur();
  }

  function moveFocused($item, dir) {
    var $parent = $item.parent();
    var $items = $parent.children();
    if (dir == "up" && $item.index() == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (dir == "down" && $item.index() == $items.length - 1) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log("Moving Item " + $item.index() + " " + dir);
    var cIndex = $item.index();
    var nIndex;
    var float = $item.detach();
    if (dir == "up") {
      nIndex = cIndex - 1;
      $items.eq(nIndex).before(float);
    }
    if (dir == "down") {
      nIndex = cIndex + 1;
      $items.eq(nIndex).after(float);
    }
    $parent.sortable("refresh");
  }

  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable li").click(clickFocus)
  $("html").keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(".ui-state-focus").length == 1) {
      console.log(e.which);
      if (e.which == 38) {
        moveFocused($(".ui-state-focus"), "up");
      }
      if (e.which == 40) {
        moveFocused($(".ui-state-focus"), "down");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

This allows both and notice how after the item position is changed, I `refresh` the sortable so it can know the new positions of all the items.

There is a weird caveat that I have not figured out yet. When `clickFocus()` is executed, I am unable to capture the `keyup` event from `$(document)`, `$("html")`, `$("body")`, or `$("#sortable")`. You have to click on any other part of the document to then capture the event.